# Photoshop actions with auto rotate

Tags: action, photoshop, rotation

I build my action for create image thumbs, and I want add to the end of action auto rotate to my thumb.
My question is: How add rotate with *random* angle from -45 to 45 degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate an image automatically via an Adobe Script:

```
    if (!app.documents.length > 0) {
    alert("No active document");
    }
    else {
    var docRef = app.activeDocument;
    var docWidth = docRef.width.as("px");
    var docHeight = docRef.height.as("px");

    if (docWidth > docHeight) {
    docRef.rotateCanvas(90);
    }
    }
```

Random numbers can be generated with:

```
this.rawValue = Math.random() * (45 - 1) + 1;
```

I've not done enough Adobe Script to tell you how to put this all together, but I'm sure you are clever enough!

Helpful site: http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/photoshop-scripts.html

Enjoi!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for another answer, I didn't want to make my other one massive and unreadable.

I have attempted (*VERY BADLY*) the script (and, for the record, it's not been tested or anything and I'm not great at this)

```
if (!app.documents.length > 0) {
    alert("No active document"); //no document?! whats happening?!
} else {
    var docRef = app.activeDocument;
    var docWidth = docRef.width.as("px");
    var docHeight = docRef.height.as("px");

    if (docWidth > docHeight) { //if width is greater than height
        PlusMinus.rawValue = Math.random() * (2 - 1) + 1; //GET 1 OR 2
        if (PlusMinus.rawValue == 1) {
            deLimit = "-"; //set minus if its a 1
        } else {
            deLimit = "+"; //set plus if its a 2
        }
        Angles.rawValue = Math.random() * (45 - 1) + 1; //GET NUMBER FROM 1-45
        docRef.rotateCanvas(deLimit+Angles);
    }
}
```

I'm sure you will get the idea from that!

Comment: I would use `Math.random() * 90 - 45` to get a random angle from -45 to 45. Your method eliminates all values between -1 and 1.

Comment: Cheers @Gabe, there you go @kicaj - us great people are helping you out!